# Is there a way to set the Docker container's mac address in docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Currently I'm using the following command to start a container with a predefined mac address:

```
docker run -d --lxc-conf="lxc.network.hwaddr=00:50:56:8E:8B:77:00:00" --name=my_container my_image
```

I'd like to know if there was a way to define the mac address of a container declared in a docker-compose.yml file.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`mac_address: xyz`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#mac_address) to configure the service.

```
services:
  my_container:
    mac_address: 00-50-56...
```

Both forms of MAC address ([00:50:56...](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/982#issuecomment-262589598) and 00-50-56...) should work.

This used to be a "legacy" option but appears to now be fully supported.

Comment: Beware of MAC addresses having the lowest bit set in the first byte. That makes the address a multicast address. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address. Such addresses cannot be assigned by docker. So, that's may be an unlucky example... The [mac_address](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#mac_address) is still described in the [current documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#mac_address). So IMHO that's not a legacy option. Tried with 3.7 and 3.8 and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, they must have changed the status since. I've updated the answer. And also included the MAC address from the question for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is in the feature backlog for Compose but it doesn't look like work has been started yet. [Github issue.](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/754)